# Анонимный метод и событие. Почему оно работает?

Tags: c#

Господа, вопрос может показаться странным, но я случайно написал код с ошибкой, однако он работает. Почему?

```
using System;
delegate void Del(int y);
class a
{
    public event Del CorrectXEv;
    public int x = 99;
    public void CorrectX(int y)
    {
        x = y;
        if (CorrectXEv != null) CorrectXEv(5);
    }
}
class b
{
    static void Main()
    {
        a A = new a();
        A.CorrectXEv += delegate { Console.WriteLine("X is correcting"); };
        A.CorrectX(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
    }
}
```

Ведь сигнатура анонимного метода не соответствует сигнатуре делегата, почему код выполняется?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это такой синтаксический сахар - компилятор самостоятельно "догенерирует" параметры анонимного метода. Вот что об этом говорится в спецификации языка:

> anonymous-method-expressions permit the parameter list to be omitted entirely, yielding convertibility to delegate types of any list of value parameters.

Comment: Спасибо! Так понятнее.